# Bootstrap 3.3 как правильно использовать форму с таблицей

Tags: html, bootstrap, form, table

Как правильно использовать форму с таблицей в Bootstrap 3.3.
При выполнении цикла формируется таблица содержащая несколько строк и столбцов.
Столбцы содержат по одному элементу input textarea select в каждой строке.
При submit отправляется вся таблица и обрабатывается.

Собственно вопрос: как правильно должен быть сформирован HTML для Bootstrap

```
<form method=POST ><table class='table table-striped table-condensed'>
<thead><tr><th>ID<th>NAME<th>SELECT<th>UPDATE<th>INSERT<th>ALLOW</thead><tbody>
<tr>
    <td>1<input type=hidden name='update[0][ID]' value='1'>
    <td><input type=text name='update[0][NAME]' value='Запрос 1'>
    <td><textarea  rows='3' name='update[0][SELECT]' wrap='hard'>SELECT </textarea>
    <td><textarea  rows='3' name='update[0][UPDATE]' wrap='hard'>update </textarea>
    <td><textarea  rows='3' name='update[0][INSERT]' wrap='hard'>insert into </textarea>
    <td><input type=text name='update[0][ALLOW]' value='*'>
<tr>
    <td>2<input type=hidden name='update[1][ID]' value='2'>
    <td><input type=text name='update[1][NAME]' value='Запрос 2'>
    <td><textarea  rows='3' name='update[1][SELECT]' wrap='hard'>select </textarea>
    <td><textarea  rows='3' name='update[1][UPDATE]' wrap='hard'></textarea>
    <td><textarea  rows='3' name='update[1][INSERT]' wrap='hard'></textarea>
    <td><input type=text name='update[1][ALLOW]' value='*'>
<tr>
    <td>3<input type=hidden name='update[2][ID]' value='3'>
    <td><input type=text name='update[2][NAME]' value='Запрос 3'>
    <td><textarea  rows='3' name='update[2][SELECT]' wrap='hard'>SELECT </textarea>
    <td><textarea  rows='3' name='update[2][UPDATE]' wrap='hard'></textarea>
    <td><textarea  rows='3' name='update[2][INSERT]' wrap='hard'></textarea>
    <td><input type=text name='update[2][ALLOW]' value='*'>
</tbody></table>
<div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-6'>
  <input class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' type=submit name='Save' style='width:100%' value='Save'>
</div></form>
```

Comment: Привет выложите Ваш код вывода записей в цикле

Comment: Сам цикл роли не играет и может быть написан на любом языке. Главное это результат